# JSON encoding by browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am sending the below JSON as response:

```
{
    "employees": [
        { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, // response json
        { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
    ]
}
```

But all my browsers are interpreting the above JSON as

```
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },   // interpreted json
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
```

It is trailing out the wrapped object of the JSON.

Comment: Please show us the code where you send the JSON, and when you retrieve it.

Comment: i couldn't show as my website is not live

Comment: It's unclear from your question how the response is interpreted. Is it an array with two entries? Is the rest of the response (enclosing object, `employees`) gone? And what does interpreted mean? Do you call `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: i could solve the issue,before i was using the older version of jaxb library...i replaced with new one and it started working..thanx all

Answer (score 0):

I thought that was because by default, the first tag is already read. It is however,that you can still loop through the records, since they are still in array format.

To prevent this, you should include another tag, for example:

```
{
   "data":{
      "employees":[
         {
            "firstName":"John",
            "lastName":"Doe"
         },
         {
            "firstName":"Peter",
            "lastName":"Jones"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: if i sent as above it will interpret from employees,which is of no use